# An Example on Mixture Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $U$ be a uniform random variable on $(0, 1)$ and $Y$ be a Bernoulli random variable with $0.5$ as parameter. In addition, $U$ and $Y$ are independent. Now, define $X:= U+Y$. I think $X$ is a uniform random variable on $(0, 2)$. Is this conclusion correct, please? If so, how do I justify it in a formal way, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. If two distributions have the same [moment-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) (MGF), then they are identical at almost all points and have the same distribution function $F(x)$ for all $x$. Also, the moment-generating function of a sum of random variables is the product of the moment generating function of the variables.

The MGF for the Bernoulli with parameter $p, (q = 1 - p)$ and the continuous uniform with parameters $a, b$are:
$$
\begin{align}
MGF_B &= pe^t + q\\
MGF_{CU} &= \frac{e^{tb} - e^{ta}}{t(b - a)}
\end{align}
$$

In our specific case we have $p = 0.5, a = 0, b = 1$, so:
$$
\begin{align}
MGF_B &= \frac{1}{2}e^t + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{e^t + 1}{2}\\
MGF_{CU} &= \frac{e^{t} - 1}{t}
\end{align}
$$

The product of the two is:
$$
\frac{e^{2t} - 1}{2t}
$$

This is just the MGF of the continuous uniform with $a = 0$ and $b = 2$, so the the two have the same distribution.